# Oracle Apex 999 characters limitation

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, varchar2

I am using Oracle Apex Express 5.1.1.00.08. I have enough room on my table spaces.
My workspace has currently 25 database applications and a total file size of 12 MB. I know at some point in the past populating a varchar2(4000) variable worked well. Today is not working anymore. All my variables are truncated at 999 characters. I tryed even with an hidden item from Apex; I populated it with more than 1000 characters and when I wanted to display the content of it I get 999 characters followed by ~ character.

Maybe I hit a limitation in Apex or it's a bug, I do not understand. I searched the internet, nothing found. I searched Administration pages of Apex, nothing found.

Do you have a clue about it?

Comment: Update: I deleted some old apps under the workspace. I reduced the size at 10 MB used out of 15 MB allowed for the workspace. I still reproduce the problem. I am unable to execute sql queries with more than 1000 characters even they are stored in varchar2(4000) variables.

Comment: Have you been doing anything odd regarding character sets ? 4000 bytes may only fit 1000 characters if you are handling 4 byte characters.

Comment: @GaryMyers, just tested a varchar2(10000). Same behaviour. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is very unusual and points to something strange within your specific configuration / architecture.

What are you using for the middle tier? (ORDS, EPG, OHS) 
Could you try installing the latest version of ORDS (standalone even on the same server as the DB) to see if the problem persists.

If you log a Service Request with Oracle Support they may be able to help isolate the issue.

Regards,
David

Comment: No need for mid-tier as I am using Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, I can use the embedded PL/SQL gateway. We will open soon a SR in MOS.

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense. I can't think of anything that would cause an item to end with a ~ character. How are you checking the value of the hidden item, actually looking at the value on the page or in the Apex debugging info?